# How to Multithread when already extending a class

Tags: java, multithreading, class, oop, thread-sleep

I have a Java class which already extends the Java default UnicastRemoteObject:

```
public class ApplicationServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ApplicationServer
```

I wish to create a thread within this class to perform a check periodically using thread.sleep - could someone please show me how this is possible if I am already extending a default Java class.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html rarely, if ever, do you extend `Thread`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take a look at some tutorials for threads.

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

The tutorial shows you that you can fork a thread by implementing `Runnable`:

```
public class ApplicationServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject
    implements ApplicationServer, Runnable {
    ...
```

Then you can fork the thread like:

```
new Thread(new ApplicationServerImpl()).start();
```

Implementing `Runnable` is better because you can extend other classes.

You also should look into using the `ExecutorService` classes which take care of much of the thread work from you:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html